# Application not installed on new phone

Tags: android-studio

I'm newbie and first time to pushlish apk file to install on the real phone with unknown source and got the problem "Application not installed" even first time install this app.
My phone is galaxy s3 android 4.3
My app minSDK is 15 and max is 28
I don't have experience so please help how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the both box V1 and V2 and work.